# How to get an Array of parents and children of categories in mangoose (Materialised Path Category)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, categories

Hello guys I wanted to implement Materialised Path Category Hierarchy to mongodb in nodejs application and if I have those 2 docs and I want to get array of all of them like a tree as I will explain

The collections:

```
const categoriesCollection = [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "electronics"
    , "parent": "/"
    , "category": "/electronics"
  },


  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "embedded"
    , "parent": "/electronics"
    , "category": "/electronics/embedded"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "controllers"
    , "parent": "/electronics"
    , "category": "/electronics/controllers"
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "cases"
    , "parent": "/electronics"
    , "category": "/electronics/cases"
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "big"
    , "parent": "/electronics/cases"
    , "category": "/electronics/cases/big"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "small"
    , "parent": "/electronics/cases"
    , "category": "/electronics/cases/small"
  },


]

const ProductsCollection = [
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "product1"
    , "cost": 125
    , "currency": "USD"
    , "categories": ["/electronics/embedded"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "product2"
    , "cost": 134
    , "currency": "USD"
    , "categories": ["/electronics/controllers"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "product3"
    , "cost": 133
    , "currency": "USD"
    , "categories": ["/electronics/cases/big"]
  },

  {
    "_id": ObjectId("54fd7392742abeef6186a68e")
    , "name": "product4"
    , "cost": 188
    , "currency": "USD"
    , "categories": ["/electronics/cases/small", "/electronics/cases"]
  },

]
```

I want to have output Array of parents and children and products in a tree alike like that:

```
const allCategories = [
  {

    name: "electronics",
    categories: [
      {
        name: "embedded",
        categories: [],
        products: [{ name: "product1" }]
      },
      {
        name: "controllers",
        categories: [],
        products: [{ name: "product2" }]
      },
      {
        name: "cases",
        categories: [
          {
            name: "big",
            categories: [],
            products: [{ name: "product3" }]
          },
          {
            name: "small",
            categories: [],
            products: [{ name: "product4" }]
          }
        ],
        products: [{ name: "product1" }]
      },

    ]

    ,
    products: [{ "name": "product4" }]

  }
]
```

How can I get this array in this array by mongoose queries?

Answer (score 0):

There is no any straight way to handle this situation in MongoDB, You can try [$groupLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/index.html) and custom logic,

- `$match` filter that records only have `parent` is `/`
- `$graphLookup` to get child records and depth number in depthField `level`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `categories` array and allow to not remove empty category
- `$lookup` with `products` collection and join products or categories
- `$addFields` to select only `name` field in `products`
- `$sort` by depth level field `level` in descending order
- `$group` by `category` field and reconstruct `categories` array

```
db.category.aggregate([
  { $match: { parent: "/" } },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "category",
      startWith: "$category",
      connectFromField: "category",
      connectToField: "parent",
      depthField: "level",
      as: "categories"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$categories",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "categories.category",
      foreignField: "categories",
      as: "categories.products"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "categories.products": {
        $map: {
          input: "$categories.products",
          in: { name: "$$this.name" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { "categories.level": -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$category",
      parent: { $first: "$parent" },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      categories: { $push: "$categories" }
    }
  },
```

- `$addFields` now find the nested level category and allocate to its level,

  - $reduce to iterate loop of `categories` array.
  - initialize default field `level` default value is -1, `presentChild` is [], `prevChild` is [] for the conditions purpose
  - `$let` to initialize fields:

    - `prev` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `prevChild` otherwise return `presentChild`
    - `current` as per condition if both `level` are equal then return `presentChild` otherwise []
  - `in` to return `level` field and `prevChild` field from initialized fields

    - `presentChild` `$filter` `categories` from `prev` array and return, merge current objects with `categories` array using `$mergeObjects` and concat with `current` array of let using `$concatArrays`
- `$addFields` to return only `presentChild` array because we only required that processed array

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      categories: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$categories",
          initialValue: { level: -1, presentChild: [], prevChild: [] },
          in: {
            $let: {
              vars: {
                prev: {
                  $cond: [
                    { $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] },
                    "$$value.prevChild",
                    "$$value.presentChild"
                  ]
                },
                current: {
                  $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$value.level", "$$this.level"] }, "$$value.presentChild", []]
                }
              },
              in: {
                level: "$$this.level",
                prevChild: "$$prev",
                presentChild: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$current",
                    [
                      {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$this",
                          {
                            categories: {
                              $filter: {
                                input: "$$prev",
                                as: "e",
                                cond: { $eq: ["$$e.parent", "$$this.category"] }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { categories: "$categories.presentChild" } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5DzCzVaPQ8k)

> **NOTE:** This will cause the performance issues in huge data!

Comment: Thanks for your very clear answer, so is there any simple way that doesn't cause performance issue (my goal is display categories and products in front end)?

Comment: i don't think is there any easy way to do this.

Comment: Thanks,  can u give me how to achieve this by pure vanilla javasctipt logic?

Comment: It would be good if you ask new question with specifying vanilla js tag, you will get better answers for vanilla js.